# incrementing counter in tkinter stored as variable

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, button

#CODE

```
global counter

counter = tk.IntVar()

def OnClickYes(self, event=None):
    global counter
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

def OnClickNo(self, event=None):
    global counter
    counter.set(counter.get() + 0)
```

This is for a Tkinter "survey" type program where depending on how you answer throughout the survey will give you a different results page text.
This will not work as I am getting errors that counter is not defined, and the functions will not work in the command function of my buttons.
Further info can be provided.

Comment: Show us a [mcve] please.

Comment: have you given `counter` a default value, like `counter = 0` or `counter = 1` under the `counter = tk.IntVar()`?

Comment: Your posted code should not produce the exception you mentioned.

Comment: @t0mas Can I give you a link to the full code? it is annotated for clarification where the problems are.

Comment: @Novel Can I give you a link to the full code, it is annotated for clarifacation.

Comment: No, edit your question to include a minimal working example. Or try a more beginner oriented forum like learnpython.reddit.com that has more of a discussion style.